# How to use zend_db_select to update when there is two clause

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db

I want to update an entry in the table when 2 conditions are met.

I have this statement, but it is only for one where condition

```
$this->dbo->update('mytable', $data, $this->dbo->quoteInto('id= ?', $id));
```

Instead of just checking where for just "id", i want to check for userid also..

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something similar to this should work as the $where argument will accept and parse an array, reference the `_whereExpr()` method in `Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract` for the code on how the `$where` arg is processed:

```
$this->dbo->update('mytable', $data, array('id= ?'=> $id, 'user_id=?'=>$userId));
```

I'm going to suggest that you may wish to alter you approach and use the save() method of Zend_Db_Table_Row instead of update. Here's an example.

```
 public function saveUser($id, array $userData, $userId = null)
    {
        //$this->getDbAdapter is a placeholder for your choice of db adapters, I suggest a DbTable model that extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
        $select = $this->getDbAdapter()->select();
        //if userId is not null build a where clause
        if (!is_null($userId)) {          
            $select->where('user_id = ?', $userId);
        }
        //build where clause for primary key, two where() in select() will be 'AND' use orWhere() for 'OR'
        $select->where('id = ?', $id);
        //fetch the row you wish to alter
        $row = $this->getDbAdapter()->fetchRow($select);
        //assign the data to the row, you can update any or all columns
        $row->username = $userData[username];
        $row->user_id = $userData[user_id];
        //ect...

        //save the new data to the row, will only update changed coluns
        $row->save();
        //return the whole for use in other ways, save() typically only returnbs the primary key.
        return $row;
    }
```

Yes this method is a little more verbose and maybe a touch more complicated. However as you start bumping up against the limits of 'INSERT' and 'UPDATE', save() can provide some useful functionality.